# Finding keyword in strings c++

Tags: c++, vector, nlp, chatbot

I'm still fairly new to C++ and programming so I might just be missing something big here.

I'm trying to create a chatbot for a library, deals with opening times ect and other things. I want the chatbot to be able to pickup key words in a input and then be able to call the right function that will be able to give some text back to them.

For example:

user: what time is the library open till?
//chatbot picks up the key word 'open' and returns the right function
chatbot: the libraries open between 6 and 5

It shouldn't be as hard as I am finding it to be able to get the chatbot to do this.

The function I'm having trouble with:

```
std::string GetKeywords(){
std::string KQuery = GetQuery();


std::vector<std::string> keywords{"open", "opening", "times", "close", "closing", "shut"};


    if(std::find(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(), KQuery) != keywords.end()){
        std::cout << "Library is open when I say it is" << std::endl;
    }
return 0;
};
```

This is returning a memory error and is the only place in my code which throws an issue.

All my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "FinalProject.hpp"

//introducing funtions
void PrintIntro();
std::string GetQuery();
std::string RunScripts();
std::string GetKeywords();;

// introducing chatbot
RunScript ChatBot;


int main(){

PrintIntro();
GetQuery();
GetKeywords();

};



void PrintIntro(){
    //printing introductory text to ask the user for input
std::cout << "Hi, I'm Librarius, I'm here to help you with University     library queries" << std::endl;
std::cout << "I can help you with the following: \n Spaces to study \n     Opening times \n Taking out books \n Returning books\n" << std:: endl;
std::cout << "Ask away!" << std::endl;
return;
};



std::string GetQuery(){
//getting input from the user
std::string Query = "";
std::getline(std::cin, Query);

if(Query.empty()){
    //checking to see if the user hasnt entered anything
    std::cout << "Hey! Why didnt you enter anything?! I don't want to waste my time!" << std::endl;
};

return Query;
};

std::string GetKeywords(){
std::string KQuery = GetQuery();


std::vector<std::string> keywords{"open", "opening", "times", "close", "closing", "shut"};


    if(std::find(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(), KQuery) != keywords.end()){
        std::cout << "Library is open when I say it is" << std::endl;
    }



return 0;
};

//using the input got from the user to decide which script to run

//TODO analyse the users keywords and decide on a script to run

//TODO return an appropriate script
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not all your code: `..\main.cpp:5:10: fatal error: FinalProject.hpp: No such file or directory`. We'd rather have a [mcve] than all your code, actually.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with

```
std::find(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(), KQuery)
```

is it is going to see if the entire string in `KQuery` matches one of your keywords.  Since `KQuery` has a sentence in it, it isn't going to find a match.  What you need to do is loop through all the keywords and see if `KQuery.find(keyword)` returns a valid result.

You can do that using `std::find_if` and a lambda like

```
std::find_if(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(),
             [&](auto const& keyword){ return KQuery.find(keyword) != std::string::npos; });
```

This will return an iterator to the first keyword it finds in `KQuery` or `keywords.end()` if none of the keywords are found.